# Create Trusted Location - with prompt/warning?

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

I am trying to create a folder (local drive) and start the process of making it a Trusted Location, but the user be notified and asked: Do you wish c:\Databases to be a Trusted Location?

I have found various posts here and elsewhere discussing how to create a Trusted Location by utilising registry keys.  I will not get permission from my IT department to do this so am hoping instead of asking the user to set the location up in Access from scratch, there is a way I can do the bulk of it in a script for them and they receive a warning message to authorise it.

Does anyone know if this is possible, or seen something similar done before?  I have only seen the manual setup and registry key method.

Comment: *"I have found various posts here and elsewhere discussing how to create a Trusted Location by utilising registry keys. I will not get permission from my IT department to do this"* - Those registry entries are in HKEY_CURRENT_USER so there should be no reason why your application cannot manipulate them along with whatever prompts you want.

Comment: Thanks for replying Gord.  If our IT department knew I was doing anything with the registry however they'd go ballistic.  I was hoping there was a way to get to the 'create trusted location' level and allow the user to complete via a Microsoft prompt or one of the software's screens.  That way it would still be the Office application creating the trusted location and my hands would be clean.

Comment: Whether you automate Access or you (correctly) update the HKCU registry entries directly the end result is **exactly** the same. If your IT department doesn't understand that then your problem is more political than technical and you might want to search [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) for advice on how to deal with ignorant and intransigent IT departments.